# Pass exception object to API parameter in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working in Exception Logging, I have created API for that, API taking exception as parameter and few more thing.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Log")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Post([FromBody] WP2Exceptions wp2Exceptions)
        {
            ExceptionsModel exceptionsModel = new ExceptionsModel();

                exceptionsModel = _exceptions.GetExceptionsByType(wp2Exceptions.exception.GetType().ToString());
                ExceptionsLogModel exceptionLogModel = new ExceptionsLogModel();
                exceptionLogModel.ExceptionID = exceptionsModel.ExceptionID;
                exceptionLogModel.ModuleName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
                exceptionLogModel.ExceptionMessage = wp2Exceptions.exception.Message;
                exceptionLogModel.ExceptionType = wp2Exceptions.exception.GetType().ToString();
                exceptionLogModel.ExceptionSource = wp2Exceptions.exception.Source.ToString();
                exceptionLogModel.ExceptionUrl = wp2Exceptions.exception.StackTrace;
                _exceptionsLog.AddExceptionsLog(exceptionLogModel);

            return new string[] { exceptionsModel.ExceptionType, exceptionsModel.Message };
        }

public class WP2Exceptions
    {
        public string moduleName { get; set; }
        public Exception exception { get; set; }
    }
```

While i am passing exception in parameter i am getting "Bad Request" error

**Test Code**

```
public async void callAPI()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50558/");
    try
    {
        string s = null;
        string sp = s.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var mydata = "{'exception':'" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)  + "','moduleName':'WEBAPI'}";
        var response = await client.PostAsync("Log", new StringContent(mydata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (response != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Log ID - " + response.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Please correct me where i am doing wrong or is it possible can we pass **exception object** as a WEB API parameter?

Comment: You can send any object to an HTTP enpoint as long as you serialize it eg to JSON or XML or even plain text. Instead of concatenating strings though, you could just create a `mydata` object with the properties you want and serialize it. You could use an anonymous type, eg `var myData=new {exception=ex,moduleName="WebApi"}; var str=JsonConvert.SeriqalizeObject(myData);`

Comment: `Bad Request` is returned if the request is actually bad, eg due to an inappropriate header. Use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what's actually sent to the server. It may be that concatenating strings resulted in an invalid JSON string. A single quote in the exception message, or a generic type declaration would be enough to create an invalid string

Comment: @pangaiotis not working. still same issue,
await client.PostAsync("Log", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mydata), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

Comment: Because a bad request isn't caused by the content. It's another issue, like a bad header. The string concatenation you used though adds complexity and allows even more bugs to creep in. Did you use Fiddler? What did the request look like? What did the serialized exception look like? Was it too big perhaps? Can you post a different object?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem,

In remove below code.

```
var mydata = "{'exception':'" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)  + "','moduleName':'WEBAPI'}";
```

Created new class and pass the data .

```
public class paramObject
{
    public string modulename { get; set; }
    public Exception exception { get; set; }
}
```

Inside callAPI method i implement following code.

```
pramObject po = new pramObject()
{
    modulename="Webapi",
    exception=ex,
};
var response = await client.PostAsync("Log", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(po), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```